# Can I parse hg19.2bit with php?

Tags: php, parsing, genome

I know this is possibly an obscure use for php, but I'm working on an idea to navigate the human genome in a rather interesting way.

The problem is I need to know if I can write a php script to parse the freely available data, and if so how would I start? Are there any php scripts to do this in existence?

Comment: "Can"? Sure. Almost any Turing-complete language can have a parser written in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a database design (MySQL) that has the subset of data you want to explore in the PHP application.

Then find a way to upload the data into that data schema. For the uploading part you could use a more poweful language than PHP of your choice, it could be C#, F#, Haskell, or whatever.

This seperation will help simplify things more than doing it all in PHP.

Comment: This is not a php application, and the idea of course is to store the data in a database like mySQL. The question was how do I go about parsing the HG19.2bit file using php.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write a parser for that, but that should be fairly simple: 
http://jc.unternet.net/genome/2bitformat.html

And an example in Perl: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=672251

Comment: I'm getting there but not quite. I can perhaps use `unpack()` in php but the file size is nearly 800MB.

Comment: You may want to look into the Zend IO Reader from the php-reader project. I haven't played with it myself, but it sounds like it would do the trick: http://code.google.com/p/php-reader/source/browse/trunk/src/Zend/Io/Reader.php and http://code.google.com/p/php-reader/